# This jQuery slide show doen't work in IE 8? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  

 //Execute the slideShow, set 4 seconds for each images
 slideShow(2000);

});

function slideShow(speed) {


 //append a LI item to the UL list for displaying caption
 $('ul.slideshow').append('<li id="slideshow-caption" class="caption"><div class="slideshow-caption-container"><h3></h3><p></p></div></li>');

 //Set the opacity of all images to 0
 $('ul.slideshow li').css({opacity: 0.0});

 //Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
 $('ul.slideshow li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

 //Get the caption of the first image from REL attribute and display it
 $('#slideshow-caption h3').html($('ul.slideshow a:first').find('img').attr('title'));
 $('#slideshow-caption p').html($('ul.slideshow a:first').find('img').attr('alt'));

 //Display the caption
 $('#slideshow-caption').css({opacity: 0.7, bottom:0});

 //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow 
 var timer = setInterval('gallery()',speed);

 //pause the slideshow on mouse over
 $('ul.slideshow').hover(
  function () {
   clearInterval(timer); 
  },  
  function () {
   timer = setInterval('gallery()',speed);   
  }
 );

}

function gallery() {


 //if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
 var current = ($('ul.slideshow li.show')?  $('ul.slideshow li.show') : $('#ul.slideshow li:first'));

 //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
 var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().attr('id') == 'slideshow-caption')? $('ul.slideshow li:first') :current.next()) : $('ul.slideshow li:first'));

 //Get next image caption
 var title = next.find('img').attr('title'); 
 var desc = next.find('img').attr('alt'); 

 //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
 next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

 //Hide the caption first, and then set and display the caption
 $('#slideshow-caption').slideToggle(300, function () { 
  $('#slideshow-caption h3').html(title); 
  $('#slideshow-caption p').html(desc); 
  $('#slideshow-caption').slideToggle(500); 
 });  

 //Hide the current image
 current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000).removeClass('show');

}
</script>
```

Note: this is not my script, it came from John Rausch's site.

#### Update:

Yikes, I didn't realize it was going to format like that! Let me repost just a link to his site. Don't want to give anybody eyestrain

http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

Comment: What have you tried to fix the issue so far? Are there errors? I don't think you'll get an answer if your ask your question like this.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? What happens in IE8? What happens in other browsers?

Comment: I'd start with putting your object property names and values in quotes (in order to avoid variable name conflicts). IE tends to be more sensitive than other browsers in that regard.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  You might want to add some more info about the issue, I can see there is an overlay fix for IE.  Fixing stuff for IE8 can be a headache, I would recommend finding a slideshow compatible with IE.  You can also use a meta tag to have it render in IE7 compatibility view, which it should be working in (according to the dev's site).

Comment: In IE8 the first image just sits there; the other images never appear.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in IE. **[Try it out with this jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4u6zB/)**. Not sure it's the best slideshow.

I would put the object property name and values in quotes, just to avoid any possible variable name clashes. So I would wirte

```
current.animate({"opacity": "0.0"}, 1000).removeClass('show');
```

and not `...({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)...`

Also, don't use eval for you setTimeouts, just use a function reference or an anonymous function. So I would write:

```
var timer = setInterval(gallery,speed);
```

and not `... setInterval('gallery()',speed);`

Not sure what your CSS positioning looks like, but it seems like that'd be tricky with this slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

ie is a pain. Why don't try with ie tags?

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

It worked for me on CSS, sure it can work with JS.